# QUnit - Testing functions of files besides formatter.js

Tags: javascript, junit, sapui5, qunit

The example given by UI5 of testing the formatter functions i.e.

```
// Assert
assert.strictEqual(fnIsolatedFormatter("A"), "New", "The long text for status A is correct");
assert.strictEqual(fnIsolatedFormatter("B"), "In Progress", "The long text for status B is correct");
assert.strictEqual(fnIsolatedFormatter("C"), "Done", "The long text for status C is correct");
assert.strictEqual(fnIsolatedFormatter("Foo"), "Foo", "The long text for status Foo is correct");
```

Works out very well, however, the same testing applied to functions of a controller file i.e. `Example.controller.js`, produces an `error`.

By trying to test the `_onTestFunction` of the `Example.controller` i do get the following `error`:

```
TypeError: Example._onTestFunction is not a function
```

**Question**: How do i test functions of a controller file that isn't `formatter` ?

Comment: A formatter contains static methods. A controller might need to be instanciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test a controller, you need to instantiate one:
`let controllerUnderTest = new Controller(...)`. If the Controller has any dependencies (as this is usually the case), these dependencies need to be mocked. For this, use a framework such as `sinon`. Then you can specify in each test how these mocks should behave. Once you have instantiated the controller, you can execute a method and add assertions.
In your case, it looks like you are trying to call the `_onTestFunction` not on an object, but on the "definition" of the Controller. This does not contain the method, as expected, and results in the error.